# Do mobile coolers prevent battery from bloating?

Tags: battery

Do any of those mobile coolers help prevent battery from bloating? or it'll just bloat due to natural aging? I'm a hardcore gamer so I play games all the time. All my previous phone tend to bloat within 1-2yrs so I'm just wondering if a mobile cooler is gonna help prevent battery from bloating?

Comment: Are you usually playing with a charger connected?

Comment: @Robert no I don't